# How to click a button n times Inside using for loop in Selenium Webdriver using Java Script

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to clear all the items in cart using remove button in Individual Items. I am able to get count of all the remove buttons in Cart.

This is running asynchronously and some times it misses to remove an item. I wanted to remove items one by one in synchronous manner.

I am new to promise and not sure exactly how to use promise for this.

```
$browser.findElements($driver.By.xpath(target)).then(function(elements) {
            deletebuttoncount = elements.length;
            console.log("Total Sku Available in Checkout page: ", deletebuttoncount);
            for (i = 1; i <= deletebuttoncount; i++) {
                $browser.findElement($driver.By.xpath(target)).then(function(element) {
                        element.click();
                        console.log("Deleted ", i, " Skus");
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: Why not just iterate over `elements` which is a collection of HTML Nodes inside your loop and click the button? In code: `for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {` and then `elements[i].click(); /* other code */ }`.

Comment: Problem is, click will not happen in Synchronous manner. Code is not waiting for first click to complete.

Comment: Then add the code inside an `async` function and in your loop, `await` every click. The click method does not return a promise so you may need to wrap that inside a `Promise` as well.